# syncing Highcharts horizontally that range in number of y-axis titles and also no y-axis titles

Tags: highcharts, alignment

Im trying to sync Highcharts horizontally, stacked with multiple charts  vertically- with the goal that the x axis align - some charts have hourly data for a specific range, some have daily data, some have 5-minute data.  One grid might have 2 y-axis, zero, or even 3. How to I  Align them  horizontally?

[Image showing unaligned stacked highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqOOA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a chart with the biggest `plotLeft` property and apply the same to the others by `marginLeft` property:

```
    charts.forEach(function(ch) {
        if (ch.plotLeft > maxPlotLeft) {
            maxPlotLeft = ch.plotLeft;
        }
    });

    charts.forEach(function(ch) {
        ch.update({
            chart: {
                marginLeft: maxPlotLeft
            }
        });
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5012/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update